# Отправка сигнала в QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой- при emit сигнала с параметром в виде QByteArray длины до 3-х байт программа вылетает с фразой unknown signal.

```
// Слот асинхронного получения данных
void UART_Manager_C::Receive_Async()
{
    // Считать данные
    QByteArray Answer = Receive();
    // Если длина данных больше нуля
    if (Answer.length() > 0)
    {
        // Отправить сигнал
        emit Data_Received(Answer);
    }
}
```

Небольшое пояснение- это фрагмент кода класса для работы с COM портом. Внешний объект коннектится к сигналу Data_Received, в методе Receive_Async же происходит асинхронное получение данных по сигналу readyRead от порта с последующей отправкой данных в случае, если они корректны (Проверка происходит в методе Receive).

Если длина Answer больше или равна 3 байтам, то emit проходит без проблем, в противном случае код вылетает на этих строчках в файле qbytearray.h по условию i >= 0 (i, чем бы он ни был, при вылете равен -2)

```
inline QByteRef QByteArray::operator[](int i)
{ Q_ASSERT(i >= 0); return QByteRef(*this, i); }
```

В поле Проблемы QT выводит следующее

> :-1: ошибка: Возникло исключение:  Exception at 0x6b78f704, code:
>   0xc0000602: , flags=0x0.

P.S. Работаю в QT Creator с QT версии 5.12. Компилятор- MinGW 64 bit

Comment: а на какой "вашей" строке происходит вылет? Ловит ли вообще кто-то этот сигнал? Если да, то кто именно и как обрабатывает?

Comment: Проблема не в том, кто что ловит, а в том, кто что отправляет т.к. сигнал не долетает до слота, стопорясь на тех строчках, что я привел выше

Comment: Какой тип аргумента в `Data_Received`? Если по ссылке, то передаётся адрес локального объекта, который уничтожается.

Comment: void Data_Received(QByteArray Data). Вариант с тем, что я передаю ссылку с уничтожающимся объектом отлетает т.к. я работаю не с указателем, а с объектом. Да и тем более у меня аналогичный код для UDP сокета работает как часы

Comment: а это в одном потоке выполняется или в разных? и если в разных то указан ли тип в `connect(......, Qt::QueuedConnection)`

Comment: Нет. Обычное однопоточное приложение

Comment: Если у вас такая проблема, что это повторяется только при условии больше или равна 3 байта, то проблема в обрабатывающем слоте 146%. в ошибке, которую вы приводите срабатывает не ассерт, а QByteRef(*this, i);, что значит выход за границы массива. Приведите обрабатывающий слот

Comment: Ну хорошо, а колл-стек не показывает откуда там -2?

Comment: Да, действительно, @goldstar_labs, вы правы. Ошибка действительно на приеме из-за выхода за границы. Любопытно, получается, работает товарищ Debuger т.к. точки останова в обрабатывающем слоте он проигнорил, вылетая на emit, из- за чего и весь сыр-бор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была во внешнем обрабатывающем слоте. В нем происходил выход за границы массива. Спасибо @Bogdan и @goldstar_labs за помощь в решении проблемы